# how to fix six package error with executable python script produce by cx-Freeze

Tags: tkinter, cx-freeze, miniconda

I'm currently trying to produce an executable file for an application I'm developing. This application is for biologist and need some package from github etc... I can't ask them to install all packages they don't know linux.

So I've tried to use Cx-freeze in my conda dedicated envirronment.
everything work well but when I try to execute my application I've the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marion/miniconda3/envs/bio/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "/home/marion/miniconda3/envs/bio/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "NetworkReconstuct_GUI.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "/home/marion/miniconda3/envs/bio/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    import networkx.drawing
  File "/home/marion/miniconda3/envs/bio/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/drawing/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import nx_pydot
  File "/home/marion/miniconda3/envs/bio/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/drawing/nx_pydot.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import parse_version
  File "/home/marion/miniconda3/envs/bio/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from pkg_resources.extern import six
  File "/home/marion/miniconda3/envs/bio/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py", line 61, in load_module
    "distribution.".format(**locals())
ImportError: The 'six' package is required; normally this is bundled with this package so if you get this warning, consult the packager of your distribution.
```

Here I'm lost..
If anyone could explain what the problem is and how to solve it, it would be nice.

Already tried to reinstall python-six... But maybe isn't install in the great folder...

EDIT
I finnaly succesfully generate the executable file by adding manually into the setup all packages that was missing. It work on my computer but there is an error in other computer for fisher module (the program search it in ~/marion/miniconda... ) while the library has been copied in the build folder. How can I fix this?

Comment: did you try including the `six` package in your setup.py?

Comment: I had the six package in my setup it seems to work!

Comment: But now I have still trouble with the package fisher (from https://github.com/brentp/fishers_exact_test.git) I've tried the same solution it seems that the library is well included but I've the folloxing msg :     import fisher
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fisher'

Comment: Did you see the `fisher` library in the cx_freeze folder created? It should be under the `lib` folder

Comment: When I build I've no trouble with the module :

Comment: P fisher                    /home/marion/miniconda3/envs/bio/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fisher/__init__.py
m fisher.cfisher            /home/marion/miniconda3/envs/bio/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fisher/cfisher.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
copying /home/marion/miniconda3/envs/bio/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fisher/cfisher.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -> build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.6/lib/fisher/cfisher.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
copying /home/marion/miniconda3/envs/bio/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 -> build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.6/lib/fisher/libpython3.6m.so.1.0

Comment: Yes I see it in build/exe.linux..../lib